How can I retrieve only the 'next event' in console.log?
calendar.getEvents(); 

The above will of course list all events stored in client-side memory.  Is there a similar command that will list only the 'next' event that will occur from that time forward?
I can't seem to find anything in the FullCalendar.io documentation about specifically getting the next event.

No, you'd have to work that out yourself from the data the calendar returns. There's no ready-made function for it. Compare the start dates in the returned data with the current date and time.

Yes, there is no in-build method in FullCalendar.io, that directly retrieves only the "next" event. However we can achieve this by implementing a custom function that filters and sorts the events to find the next one.
Here is what we can try.
function getNextEvent() {
  const now = new Date()
  const events = calendar.getEvents()

  /* Filter events to include only those events which start in the future */

  const futureEvents = events.filter(event => event.start > now)

  /** Sort Future events by their time */
  futureEvents.sort((a, b) => a.start - b.start)

  // Return the next event (which will be first event in the sorted list) or null if no future events
  return futureEvents.length > 0 ? futureEvents[0] : null
}


const nextEvent = getNextEvent()

if (nextEvent) {
  console.log('Next event:', nextEvent.title, 'at', nextEvent.start)
} else {
  console.log('There are no upcoming events.')
}

